# Thread.sleep (change image) Java

Tags: thread-sleep

I have two jlabels with an image.. I try to change the image in a label when the other is clicked.. (such as a game)..
I have a problem..When i write the Thread.sleep the image is not change..See the code:

```java
public class Game extends JFrame{
private JLabel l1,l2;;
private boolean isClicked = false ,isClicked2 = false;
public Game(){
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    l1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image1.png")));
    add(l1);
    l2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image1.png")));
    add(l2);


    l1.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if(isClicked2){
                l1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image2.png")));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    l1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image1.png")));
                    l2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image1.png")));
                    isClicked2 = false;
                    isClicked = false;
            }catch(InterruptedException ex){}
            }
            else{
                l1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image2.png")));
                isClicked = true;
            }     
        }@Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}@Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
    });

    l2.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if(isClicked){
              try {
                    l2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image2.png")));
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    l2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image1.png")));
                    l1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image1.png")));
                isClicked = false;
                    isClicked2 = false;
              }catch(InterruptedException ex){}  
            }
            else{
                l2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image2.png")));
                isClicked2 = true;
            }     
        }@Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}@Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game g = new Game();
    g.setTitle("Fint the same");
    g.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    g.pack();
    g.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Run it and first click the fisrt label.. After click the second label and the first will change image in 1 second but the seconf label NEVER!!

Comment: You do realize that in the first listener you have `Thread.Sleep(1000)` and in the second you have `Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(1000)`, right? Don't know if that makes a difference, but that kinda jumped out at me.

Comment: Thread.sleep() is a static method, calling it on a Thread object (currentThread) doesn't change anything, it will always sleep on the current thread.

Comment: Yes..no .CurrentThread... But is th same problem.. koljaTM: What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changing of the images has to be done on the event thread (the thread used to process graphics events). Therefore setting the image will queue an appropriate event to be processed after your method returns. At that time though, the image has already changed back, because sleep()ing on the event thread doesn't allow any other events to be processed.
As dashrb said, don't sleep() the main thread, but schedule the flip back in a Timer:

```
                if (isClicked) {

                    l2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image2.png")));

                    new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                            l2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image1.png")));
                            l1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image1.png")));
                            isClicked = false;
                            isClicked2 = false;
                        }
                    }).start();

                } catch (final Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
               ...
```

Comment: Ok thanks.. I understand the problem but I don't know how to flip back in a Timer.. If able to help me would be very useful

Comment: Thank you very much!! But 1 problem :                        constructor Timer in class Timer cannot be applied to given types;
  required: int,ActionListener
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: This is a short tutorial: [how to use swing timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: I believe the example code above is based on a java.util.Timer (because a no-arg constructor is shown).  UTIL Timers are executed in arbitrary threads; in contrast, SWING Timers are executed on the event dispatch thread, which is mandatory for changing images on your swing JLabels!  The SWING Timer tutorial link is in my previous comment, and your code would look something like: `timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, this);`.  You would define a `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method in your class, rather than a `run()` method as shown above.

Comment: I think I modified this answer accordingly.  *crosses fingers*

Comment: My SWING (vs. UTIL) modification didn't stick, so I moved to a comment below.

Comment: changed to javax.swing.Timer

Answer (score 0):

You should not sleep() in these methods--they are invoked from the "event dispatch" thread, which handles all drawing events.  If you're sleeping, then the thread can't be repainting your labels.

Rather than sleeping, change your image, then create a javax.swing.Timer task which will fire 1-second-from-now to change the images again as desired.  The sample from koljaTM above uses a java.util.Timer, which runs in the "wrong" thread.  This is his code, modified to use a SWING timer:

```
            if (isClicked) {
            try {
                l2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image2.png")));
                javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        l2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image1.png")));
                        System.out.println("image2 gone");
                        l1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image1.png")));
                        isClicked = false;
                        isClicked2 = false;
                    }
                });
                timer.setRepeats(false);
                timer.start();
            } catch (final Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
           ...
```

Comment: instead of Thread.sleep() what can i do? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I modified my answer to include sample code (inspired by koljaTM above).  I hope it helps.

Comment: Now it run without compile error but unfortunately it has the same problem..  Nevertheless, thank you very much

Comment: you might need more println()'s to determine exactly what is being called, and what isn't.  The buttons look like they should behave the same.